# confusion_matrix - too many values to unpack

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to use the [confusion_matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) function, as follows:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predict).ravel()
```

`y_true` and `y_predict` are both lists. When I return their shape, I get: `(71,)`.

I'm however getting the following error for the above statement:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I'm not sure if it is because of the second (empty) dimension in `(71,)`? I'm not sure how to remove it if it is the issue here.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: writing your own confusion matrix function from y_true and y_predicted is pretty easy

Comment: This only works for binary classification. Are you sure the `y` contains only two classes.

Answer (score 5):

You can only assign multiple variables dynamically if the number of outputs is certain. If you assign the result of `confusion_matrix` to a single variable, you can then check its contents in a loop and assign the contents conditionally:

`returned = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predict).ravel()`

```
for var in returned:
    #... do stuff with each item in the returned collection
```

You could also just check its length and if it is 4, you can proceed as usual:

```
if len(returned) == 4:
    tn, fp, fn, tp = returned
```

Answer (score 4):

The line you're trying to execute `tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predict).ravel()` is valid only if you have 2 classes in output (binary classification). However, the error you get is an indicator that you have more than 2 classes (multi-class classification). In this case, there's no meaning of `tn, fp, fn, tp`. Instead you can visualize the confusion matrix (e.g. by using heatmap).